# WHERE Something IN (CASE WHEN statement)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a "select clause" according to conditional condition!
bu I have error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How can I fix it??
here is my simplified code:

```
SELECT  UnitsAllocation.UnitID
        , OrganizationUnits.Title AS UnitTitle
        , 'Title' AS ExpenseTitle1
        , SUM(UnitsAllocationDetails1.ExpenseAmount1) AS ExpenseAmount1 
FROM    [bdg_UnitsAllocation] UnitsAllocation 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT  UnitsAllocationDetails.UnitsAllocationID
                  , SUM(UnitsAllocationDetails.Amount) / 1 AS ExpenseAmount1  
          FROM    [bdg_UnitsAllocationDetails] UnitsAllocationDetails  
          WHERE   UnitsAllocationDetails.ExpenseID IN (
                    CASE 1 WHEN 1 
                    THEN ( SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE ParentId = 1 ) 
                    ELSE ( SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE Id = 1 )  
                    END
                  )  
          GROUP BY 
                  UnitsAllocationDetails.UnitsAllocationID
        ) UnitsAllocationDetails1 ON UnitsAllocationDetails1.UnitsAllocationID = UnitsAllocation.ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [bdg_OrganizationUnits] OrganizationUnits ON UnitsAllocation.UnitID = OrganizationUnits.ID 
GROUP BY 
        UnitsAllocation.UnitID, OrganizationUnits.Title
```

**please look at "CASE" and "IN" statement.**

Comment: The `1 = 1` case will always hold true. Why are you using a `CASE` there? Why not simply get rid of it, so the `SELECT ID FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE ParentId = 1` won't be an expression?

Comment: I simplified it. the when statement originally is "WHEN @Level = 1 THEN ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use a case? can't you just do

```
where (@Level = 1 and ExpenseId in (select id from bdg_expenses where parentid = 1)) or
      (@Level <> 1 and ExpenseId in (select id from bdg_expenses where id = 1))
```