# WHERE Something IN (CASE WHEN statement)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WHERE Something IN (CASE WHEN statement) ??!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415837/where-something-in-case-when-statement)

i want ro write a "select-where" cluase with cinditonal condition.
i used "case-when" in "where ID IN" clause But I have the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

here is my simplified code:

```
SELECT 
    UnitsAllocation.UnitID,
    OrganizationUnits.Title AS UnitTitle,
    'Title' AS ExpenseTitle1,
    SUM(UnitsAllocationDetails1.ExpenseAmount1) AS ExpenseAmount1
FROM
    [bdg_UnitsAllocation] UnitsAllocation LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT
            UnitsAllocationDetails.UnitsAllocationID, 
            SUM(UnitsAllocationDetails.Amount) / 1 AS ExpenseAmount1 
     FROM [bdg_UnitsAllocationDetails] UnitsAllocationDetails 
     WHERE UnitsAllocationDetails.ExpenseID IN (CASE 1 
                                                    WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE ParentId = 1)
                                                    ELSE (SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE Id = 1) 
                                                END)

     GROUP BY UnitsAllocationDetails.UnitsAllocationID) UnitsAllocationDetails1 ON UnitsAllocationDetails1.UnitsAllocationID = UnitsAllocation.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [bdg_OrganizationUnits] OrganizationUnits ON UnitsAllocation.UnitID = OrganizationUnits.ID
GROUP BY UnitsAllocation.UnitID, OrganizationUnits.Title
```

Please Look At "`WHERE UnitsAllocationDetails.ExpenseID IN ...`"
How can I fix that?

Comment: You just asked the same question. If you want to change your question, edit it, don't create a new one.

Comment: unfortunatly in my region "XXX" is forbiden pharase! and has been filtered according to OUR Internet policies. so I cant open my question to view or edit, then I asked it again. you repeated XXX again in this page!

Comment: rotfl. I have edited your original question to remove the x's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

WHERE UnitsAllocationDetails.ExpenseID IN (CASE 1 
                                                    WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE ParentId = 1)
                                                    ELSE (SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE Id = 1) 
                                                END)
use the following

WHERE UnitsAllocationDetails.ExpenseID IN (SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE ParentId = 1 and 1 = 1
                                 UNION ALL SELECT Id FROM bdg_Expenses WHERE Id = 1 and 1 <> 1
                                                )